# Passing Arabic data from node request to Java server

Tags: java, node.js, post

I am trying to send Arabic data from post request of node to Java (Glassfish server, grizzly framework, formatted to be utf-8 for request content). But the request upon receiving in the Java server shows some garbage value "ÙÙØ§ÙØ¨Ø© Ø§ÙØ¹Ø§ÙÙ " instead of Arabic text.

The request from node is:

```
var request = require('request');
request.post("http://localhost:8080/taJavaServer/taResponse", {json: true, body: "مواكبة العالم "}, function(err, res, body) {console.log(body);console.log(err)});
```

So, I dont know how to send exact same Arabic text from node's request post to Java server.

### More Info

On calling the java-api via ajax (jQuery), it works fine and Arabic text is getting detected.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/taJavaServer/taResponse",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: JSON.stringify({data: "مواكبة العالم "}),
        success: function (respon) {..}...
```

Comment: the sending is not the issue, it's the encoding you need to look at

Comment: I suspect the default encoding request post has is utf-8, which is fine, right?

Comment: UTF-8 should indeed be able to do the job, but are you sure that's the encoding you're using? what exactly are you trying to do? write it in a DB? how do you see you don't get the right characters?

Comment: I check the body of the request, It has content-encoding = utf-8 set properly. I am not writing it in a DB. I am only taking the request on the java server and see it in the console of netbeans.

Comment: so, your front-end uses UTF-8. Are you sure your backend does?

Comment: the node js post request uses UTF-8, which I am sure of. If the backend (which is in java) would not have been using the same utf-8 format, the ajax call would have been failed, which is not the case. Also, I have set the post request content encoding type setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");.

Comment: Is source file in node.js in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I am not sending it through a file, but it's through nodejs-cli

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually sending valid json, try something like this:

```
request.post("http://localhost:8080/taJavaServer/taResponse", {json: true, body: {data:"مواكبة العالم "}}, function(err, res, body) {console.log(body);console.log(err)});
```

Comment: Yes, right, even using the above json format, it does the same. 
Info:   {"data":"ÙÙØ§ÙØ¨Ø© Ø§ÙØ¹Ø§ÙÙ "}

Comment: Weird, I've tried your code and it works fine on my machine. Can you show us the java code just in case?

Comment: are you trying to send it via node repl shell to hit a foreign (in my case, java, glassfish on netbeans) api?

Comment: I sent it to a node server on my host. Can you try creating a file with this code and name it something like "client.js" (utf-8 encoded) and then call this script from command line using `node client.js` please?

Comment: Did the same and via : System.out.println(request.getContentType()); => application/json
           System.out.println(request.getCharacterEncoding()); => null
This is weird!!

Comment: although, I have set in web.xml : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Okay, got it.. I have set charset inside the header of the request explicitly:

request.post("http://localhost:8080/taJavaServer/taResponse", {json: true, headers: { host: 'localhost:8080', accept: 'application/json','content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-encoding': 'utf-8'}, body: {data:"مواكبة العالم "}}, function(err, res, body) {console.log(body);console.log(err)}); And now it is working fine

Comment: Great, very interesting though. Maybe the ajax-lib sets these headers automatically, I'll check the documentation.